# Connecting to Websphere MQ in C# works, but fails in C++ with code 2058 (MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, ibm-mq

I need to write a piece of code to put a message into MQ using C++.  When I test it on localhost, using the default port (1414) it works. However, in the actual environment, which uses specific channel definition and different port (1420), it fails with reason code 2058 / MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR. 
There is no problem connecting to the remote MQ using Websphere MQ Explorer. There is also no problem connecting to the same remote server in a C# app to prove connectivity. Any ideas what could be causing it?

Some sample code extract: C++ which fails when **.connect()** is called...

```
ImqChannel * pChannel_ = 0;  // Channel definition which is at class level
ImqQueueManager queueManager_;   // Queue Manager, also declared at class level


// extract from the MQHelper::Connect() method... 
int MQClient::Connect() {
   pChannel_ = new ImqChannel;
   pChannel_->setChannelName("CLCHL.QM");
   pChannel_->setTransportType(MQXPT_TCP);
   pChannel_->setConnectionName("10.2.3.4(1420)");
   // Should we set this???! pChannel_->setModeName("to what?");

   queueManager_.setName("QM");
   queueManager_.setChannelReference(pChannel_);

   if (!queueManager_.connect()) {
      // ERROR IS HERE: _lastCompletionCode is 2, _lastReasonCode is 2058
      _lastCompletionCode = queueManager_.completionCode();
      _lastReasonCode = queueManager_.reasonCode();
      return (int)_lastReasonCode;
   }
    // If we get here, we're all good:
   return 0;
}
```

In C#, there is no such problem: the following code will connect fine..

```
queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QM", "CLCHL.QM", "10.2.3.4(1420)");
```

**Other info:**

- Server MQ installation is  7.0.1.0 Websphere MQ Explorer version:
- 7.5.0.1 (no problem connecting here) In the C# app, I am only referencing amqmdnet.dll... all fine.
- In the C++ app, I have the external dependencies set up for the 26 various mq  .h or .hpp files.
- Also I have included the appropriate libs etc... again - I know it is
  capable of working as it the same code will work pointing to a
  localhost queue manager.
- I am using VS 2017

Any ideas?

Comment: QM name is not a mandatory field. You can try removing the QM name and see if it works or not

Comment: Hi, I commented out the .setName("QM") statement. That resulted in a reason code of 2059 / MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR.  So no joy there.

Comment: The only difference between the c# application and the c++ application could be "setTransportType(MQXPT_TCP);"

Comment: "setTransportType(MQXPT_TCP);" - that is correct - see comments below about compiling/linking of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImqChannel * pChannel_ = 0;  // Channel definition which is at class level
ImqQueueManager queueManager_;   // Queue Manager, also declared at class level
```

What's with the extra underscore in the variable names?

```
queueManager_.setName("QM");
```

Is that the ACTUAL queue manager name of the remote queue manager?  It needs to be the correct value.  Note: MQ is case sensitive. ie. "QM" is not the same as "qm".

Each queue manager's listener listens on a different port.

```
pChannel_->setConnectionName("10.2.3.4(1420)");
```

Are you sure queue manager "QM" is actually listening on port 1420 and not 1414 or 1419 or 1421 etc..

Comment: The underscores are actual variable names -- the trailing underscore is just convention I followed when adding to existing code. I realise it is a bit strange.    "QM" is definitely correct.   And the port is 1420 in the office environment (when I test on localhost host, it's obviously the default 1414).  This has been proven in the C# app which I wrote up just to prove connectivity is possible.

Comment: Firewall?  Are you running the C# program from the same PC/server as the C++ program?

Comment: Also, how did you compile/link the C++ program?  Did you link it with the Client or Server libraries?  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030490_.htm  - be careful the 4th character of the 2nd library is 'c' for client and 's' for server.  Make sure you are using the Client libraries.

Comment: This is where I was going wrong. I was not including the correct bunch of libraries in the project properties.  Works now.  Thank you.